# Qué significa el costo en una consulta utilizando EXPLAIN en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una consulta que compara el contenido de una tabla foranea contra una tabla local utilizando el EXCEPT. La cosa aquí es que utilicé el EXPLAIN VERBOSE sobre mi consulta y me regresó los siguientes datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi duda está en el COST. Estuve leyendo y habla algo sobre "unidades de captura de página de disco" pero qué significa eso?
Dice que de los dos números que salen en COST uno es el tiempo mínimo que le toma en regresar el primer dato y el segundo como el tiempo total. Pero tiempo en qué? Milisegundos?

Esos 97794.35 que sale en mi imagen qué significa? Que tomará 97.7 segundos en ejecutarse mi query?

Por cierto, la información que compara de la tabla 1 son casi 1 millón de registros contra mi tabla local que tiene ese millón de registros más otros 30 millones pertenecientes a otra tabla.

Mi consulta es de tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM tablaforanea1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM tablalocal WHERE tipo = 'tablaforanea1'
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El `cost` es una medida arbitraria en unidades determinada por varios [parámetros de configuración](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) y un cálculo basado en las estadísticas de las tablas como por ejemplo la cantidad de filas/paginas, etc, es solo para calcular el valor de un plan de ejecución y deternimar cual es más óptimo, el valor real del tiempo te lo retorna  `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,VERBOSE)` que retorna además del plan,  una parte de que te dice el tiempo real, como por ejemplo:

`(actual time=0.061..28.848 rows=10000 loops=1)`

Ahí si es tiempo de regresar el primer dato y el segundo como el tiempo total, además de la cantidad de `rows` real retornadas

Comment: Esos 28.848 me imagino son milisegundos. Y si es así significa que tarda 28.8 segundos en regresar 10000 registros? (en tu ejemplo)

Comment: si es en milisegundos,  pero es que tarda esos milisegundos en retornar los 10000 registros